# Using Apache proxy pass not forwards with port

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, proxypass, webmin

I have some websites on my server and few of them have proxy pass and they are passing some port to some subdomain.
But now I'm trying to add another subdomain for Webmin, but it doesn't forward to the port.

This is site.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.tld
    ServerName webmin.site.tld
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://'publicip':10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://'publicip':10000/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =webmin.site.tld [OR]
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmin.site.tld/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/webmin.site.tld/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the screen shot of what I see:
[image: and this is the screen shot of what I see]

Then if I use 10000 port I will see:
[image: Then if I use 10000 port I will see]

So as I know Apache doesn't forward the request to port 10000 and with the same config I have some websites running, and the bind9 is ok, certificate is ok.

What I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you exactly what to do. Use https instead of http.

```
ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.100:10000/
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.100:10000/
```

Alternativeley, configure webmin not to use https.

Comment: I tried that in apache, didn't work! :(
But I didn't config ssl on webmin let me check that.

Comment: OH! turning off ssl in miniserv.conf worked. Thank YOU.